# Как проверить, что в строке только нули?

Tags: java, android

У меня есть условие

```
if (editTextOne.getText().toString().equals("0"));
```

Я хочу добавить в equals() еще "00", "000", можно ли это как-нибудь сделать без

```
if (((editTextOne.getText().toString().equals("0")) || 
(editTextOne.getText().toString().equals("00")) || ...
```

и так далее ?

Comment: Можно разве что 0, 00, 000 поместить в список и проверять, содержит ли он строку из поля ввода.

Comment: На что проверяем? На любое количество нулей?

Comment: Эникейщик, да, на любое

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если нужно проверить состоит ли строка из одних только нулей, то можно использовать такое регулярное выражение:

```
if (str.matches("0+")) { // если 0+ то true если минимум один 0, 
                         // если 0*, то пустая строка тоже даст true.
    // код 
}
```

Если сравниваемые строки сложно задать в регулярку, то можно так:

```
 if (Stream.of("0", "01", "012").anyMatch(str::equals)) {
     // код 
 }
```